# 3D to 1D mapping function confusion

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I just finished coding a C++ program to manage a 3D matrix with dynamically allocated memory.

In order to use a contiguous chunk of memory, I decided to use a mapping function to physically store the elements of my matrix to 1D array.

For this purpose, I have a `T *_3D_matrix` pointer to the array, which is defined as

```
_3D_matrix = new T[height * width * depth];
```

where `height, width and depth` are input parameters for the constructor.

[image: Here is an example matrix and the mapping function]

The program works just fine, I even tested it with Valgrind and no memory problems happen.

What I don't get is: my array has got `height * width * depth = 12` elements, and the mapping function seems to map some elements out of the `[0..11]` range.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

This is the output I get from recreating the same matrix and printing it in my program.

[image: Index: Value]

Comment: You mapping function seems flawed. If you look at the `MAPPED_TO` column, there's no index `4` or `5` for example.

Comment: @YSC I don't get how I can store something to the index 15 in an array with 12 elements.

Comment: As for a possible way to solve it, I suggest you draw out all twelve elements in a row, mark out all sub-array just like an array of arrays of arrays would be in memory if you use that, and try to figure out an algorithm from that.

Comment: I'd guess the mapping function is flawed. Double check each value in debugger.

Comment: @YSC nope, look at the matrix on the right. `MAPPED_TO` column is the one giving me indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You computed the mapped index for out-of-bounds values of `y`.

You said `height * width * depth= 12`, and:

```
index = y * width * depth + x * depth + z
```

And we see in your table:

```
#.| Y | X | Z | index
--+---+---+---+------
1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2
2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 6
```

This implies:

1. `0 * width * depth + 1 * depth + 0 = 2` => `depth = 2`
2. `1 * width * depth + 0 * depth + 0 = 6` => `width * depth + 6` => `width = 3`
3. `height * width * depth= 12` => `height = 2`

Thus:

- y is in [0, 1]
- x is in [0, 2]
- z is in [0, 1]

The maximum index is at `{x, y, z} = {2, 1, 1}` and its value is `1 * 2 * 3 + 2 * 2 + 1 = 11`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have a "3D" array defined as

```
some_type m[1][3][2];
```

That would look something like this if we draw it:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|                                    m[0]                                       |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|         m[0][0]          |         m[0][1]          |         m[0][2]         |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| m[0][0][0] |  m[0][0][1] | m[0][1][0] |  m[0][1][1] | m[0][2][0] | m[0][2][1] |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

If `x` represents the first "dimension", `y` the second, and `z` the third, then an expressions such as `m[x][y][z]` would with a flat array be like `m[x * 3 * 2 + y * 3 + z]`. The number `3` is the number of elements in the second dimension, and `2` is the number of elements in the third dimension.

Generalized, an array like

```
some_type m[X][Y][Z];
```

would as a flat array have the formula `x * Y * Z + y * Z + z` for the index. Compared to your formula the `x` and the `y` have been switched.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your example:

- `width = 2`, `height = 3`, and `depth = 2`
- `x` is in `[0, width)`, `y` is in `[0, height)`, `z` is in `[0, depth)`

Mapping second element should be:
`1*2*2 + 0*2 + 0 = 4`, but you get `6`. I think the reason is that some of the dimensions or indices are swapped somewhere else in your code. Seems that `width` or `depth` is 3 in your case.

Comment: why would you say `height = 3` in my example? I assume `height` is the number of rows in my matrix. Btw, I edited the question with an example output and everything seems to work. I'm probably missing on something easy.

Comment: @Marco because `y` changes from 0 to 2: 3 possible values.